# Approach to this Generic Programming Scenario with Java's Paramerterized Types and Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, generic-programming, parametric-polymorphism, parameterized-types

Say I have an interface:

```
public interface Foo { public void setId(int id); public int getId(); }
```

And objects that implement that interface:

```
public class Bar implements Foo { ... } ;
```

I wish to have a generic function that creates a Map in the form of `Map<Id, Foo>`.

I also wish for member variables like `private Map<Integer, Bar> barMap` to be set to the return value of this map.

The following:

```
private <T> Map<Integer, Foo> createMap(List<? extends Foo> foos) {
    Map<Integer, Foo> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Foo>();
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        map.put(foo.getId(), foo);
    }
    return map;
}
```

is legal.

But

```
List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<Bar>();
barList.add(...);
...
Map<Integer, Bar> barMap = createMap(barList)
```

is illegal because I cannot convert from `Map<Integer, Foo>` to `Map<Integer, Bar>`. I also cannot cast the former to the latter.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You aren't using `T` for anything in your generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be utilizing that `T` (the type parameter) -

```
private <T extends Foo> Map<Integer, T> createMap(List<T> foos) {
    Map<Integer, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, T>();
    for (T foo : foos) {
```

When you do that your **generic** method returns `Map<Integer, Bar>`, with the help of type inference, instead of `Map<Integer, Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

use ? extends Foo in the return type of the createMap method. ie your key should be Integer and value is something that extends Foo.